# What do you call it when a belief or idea is held to be true only because it is repeatedly stated as true, whether or not it is true?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

word or phase for a belief or idea that is adopted or more firmly held based on hearing it repeatedly, as in an idea that is at first rejected and later adopted because the number of times the idea is presented.

Comment: The *subjects* (i.e. the people who believe the idea is true) can be said to be *brainwashed* or *indoctrinated*. The ideas themselves could be part of a *propaganda*.

Comment: There is a word close enough to what you want. See *mumpsimus*. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mumpsimus

Comment: @tchrist Not a duplicate.  The other question is asking what is the verb for repeating something over and over again, this question is asking what the noun is for the belief that results.

Comment: A related concept, for something that is widely believed but not true, is "common misconception".

Comment: A Myth. Websters Definition: any invented story, idea, or concept:
His account of the event is pure myth. 
4.
an imaginary or fictitious thing or person.
5.
an unproved or false collective belief that is used to justify a social institution.

Comment: I'd add that there is a habit here of finding very esoteric words outside any average person's vocabulary to describe things.  While those may be fine answers in some senses, they're woefully inadequate in helping a OP express something to a wider audience.  I think these questions need to stay open to give time for people to present a wide variety of choices.

Answer (score 1):

[The Illusory Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_truth_effect):

> The illusory truth effect is the idea that if you repeat something often enough, people will slowly start to believe it’s true. But a new study has revealed that the illusory truth effect is much stronger than we imagined. Because it turns out that even if a person has prior knowledge disproving a lie they’re being told, they’ll still believe the lie if it’s repeated enough.

Journal of Experimental Psychology: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022537177800121

Comment: In one study people who knew that Scotsmen wear kilts were convinced after repetition that Scotsmen wear saris.

Comment: @Chris M That rumour certainly needs scotching.

Comment: I'm sure that there are some Scotswomen who wear saris

Comment: No doubt when they realised the truth the people who had been  brainwashed were sari about it.